# Where Am I Supposed To Write My Flutter Code

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

When I open my project (Which is called "Android App") there so many different files, so which one of them am I supposed to actually write my code?

Answer (score 1):

The entry point of a Flutter app is the `lib/main.dart` file. You can add any other `dart` files you want within the `lib` folder or subfolders.

For this and other info for how to get started in Flutter, you should read the [official Flutter quick-start guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab).

Answer (score 1):

You write Flutter(Dart) code in the following path

> project_name>lib>main.dart